# Python-Comparing two strings-Unable to loop through

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop, string-matching

**What I was trying to do:** Determine if two strings match (without using comparison operators or the cmp() built-in function) by scanning each string.

**My solution:**

```
a = input('Please enter the first string to compare:')
b = input('Please enter the second string to compare: ')

while True:
    count = 0
    if a[count] != b[count]:             # code was intended to raise an alarm only after finding the first pair of different elements
        print ('Strings don\'t match! ')
        break
    else:                                # otherwise the loop goes on to scan the next pair of elements
        count = count + 1
```

**Question:** 
After testing, it seems that this script is able to compare only the first element(`[0]`) in each string. If the first elements in the two strings are the same (`a[0] == b[0]`), then it won't go on scanning the rest of the strings. And it return nothing in the interpreter. Neither would the script end itself if the `else` suite is executed.

So I'll appreciate if someone could throw some light on what went wrong with my looping mechanism, or just general critiques about this script. Thank you very much!

Comment: What about different-length strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` here:

```
def compare(s1, s2):
   if len(s1) != len(s2):
       return False
   else:
      for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
         if c1 != c2:
             return False
         else:    
             return True

>>> compare('foo', 'foo')
True
>>> compare('foo', 'fof')
False
>>> compare('foo', 'fooo')
False
```

In your code you're resetting the value of `count` to `0` in each iteration:

```
a = input('Please enter the first string to compare:')
b = input('Please enter the second string to compare: ')
if len(a) !=  len(b):            # match the length first
    print ('Strings don\'t match')
else:
    count = 0                    #declare it outside of while loop
    while count < len(a):        #loop until count < length of strings
        if a[count] != b[count]:
            print ('Strings don\'t match! ')
            break
        count = count + 1
    else:
       print ("string match")
```

Comment: But you are using `==` (!)

Comment: @AndyHayden Ah! Yes, I missed the top most line of the question, removed the `==`.

Comment: @AndyHayden : Thanks for pointing that out. Though I think it might be more clear if taken as no "direct" comparison using comparators. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 4):

You are resetting `count` to 0 each iteration of the loop. The loop therefore compares the first elements over and over and over and over again. To fix that problem, just move the `count = 0` assignment outside of the loop, like this:

```
# ...
b = input('Please enter the second string to compare: ')

count = 0
while True:
    if a[count] != b[count]:
# ...
```

---

When you have done that, you will realise that you have a second problem – the program crashes when you have reached the end of one of the strings. You might want to handle this case too.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = raw_input('Please enter the first string to compare:')
b = raw_input('Please enter the second string to compare: ')

count = 0 
if len(a) == len(b):
    while count < len(a):
        if a[count] != b[count]:             # code was intended to raise an alarm only after finding the first pair of different elements
            print ('Strings don\'t match! ')
            break
        else:                                # otherwise the loop goes on to scan the next pair of elements
            count = count + 1 
else:
    print "Strings are not of equal length"
```

Use raw_input, put count out of while loop and change while True ==> while count != len(a) to prevent "IndexError: string index out of range".

Comment: What if `b` is shorter than `a`?

Comment: But you are using `==` (!)

Comment: @glglgl That's true, the premise of the question is a little suspect!

Comment: @AndyHayden Not really. AFAICS the only thing that is forbidden is `string1 == string2` (resp. `!=`)...

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful, here is your current way (rephrased and won't cause an exception for strings of different lengths... but it won't get the correct answer either):

```
not any(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

It's worth noting that the `any` will short-circuit (like the break does in your implementation). It's still not robust if you test on substrings e.g. 'aa', 'a' you'll get a false positive...

You could instead use an outerzip (which means you're comparing the any later strings to fillvalue):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
not any(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))
```

In action:

```
def compare(s1, s2):
    return not any(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))

s1 = 'ab'
s2 = 'a'
compare(s1, s1) # True
compare(s1, s2) # False
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Though as I'm a total beginner it seems quite beyond my grasp right now. But I'll for sure save it for studying later! Thanks!